# Challenge delete policy for a question with a low quality answer

Tags: feature-request, etiquette, low-quality-posts

On my first question on a specific Stack Exchange site, someone basically answered: "You can find the answer online".

Since they're top 2%, and the answer has upvotes, it's not my place to challenge that. But I feel like I should at least be able to delete the question, because it serves no purpose for future readers, and clearly there is no interest in answering on the Stack Exchange site.

Is there, or should there be, a way to challenge the delete policy?

Comment: Are you refering to your question on ServerFault?

Comment: Read Shog9's dupe'd question or these comments (flag NAA for deletion, then delete your question); "39 
 Forgett links, @patrick. They're a red herring in all these discussions. A post that does not contain any information is not an answer. – Shog9 Mar 20 '14 at 13:22" ***and*** "58  Without any information - "try this", "click here", "tutorial" - it's not an answer. With a class name or function name etc it's a poor answer, but an answer. Ignoring what the link is to and just reading the text. Explanations turn bad answers into better answers. – Kate Gregory Mar 20 '14 at 13:23". CBOP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there, or should there be a way to challenge the delete policy?

There is a way: Get the low quality answer deleted first, and then you can delete the question.

You can flag low quality answers as "very low quality" to put them in a queue where the community can review and delete them.

If that doesn't work, you *might* want to try and raise the issue on the site specific meta to have them explain what part of the answer meets their quality guidelines and how, and if the outcome of that meta discussion is that the answer should be deleted because it doesn't meet standards, you can flag for moderator intervention.

Of course, you could also keep your question up and hope someone comes along with a better answer, instead of deleting it once the low quality answer is gone.

Comment: while that's a good approach, the answer is from a top 2% account, not a rando. And it has upvotes. I believe this is showing the substack doesnt want the question at all. To be honest, i'm just trying to delete it as quickly as possible to prevent downvotes from the same people who upvote the low quality answer.

Comment: If you think flagging won't work, I suggest you raise the issue on a site specific meta. I don't know what question/answer pair you're talking about, and a top 2% account means nothing to me, I've had to flag plenty of answers from such accounts. I'm also not familiar with the quality expectations of every site. Honestly, people that use that site daily can probably tell you better what to improve or expect. I can only give generic advice that will probably work across many communities.

Comment: Which is now gone @yagmoth555